# Why data exchange using redirection via query params/auto-form-post CANNOT be trusted even on https?

Tags: tls

This is somewhat a basic question but the reason is not spelled out clearly anywhere.

Say we have 2 web applications running on `https://one.abc.com` and `https://two.xyz.com`.
I visit `https://one.abc.com` and a page is displayed which has a button on it and when clicked, submits to `https://one.abc.com` and responds with a redirect to `htts://two.xyz.com`.
On `htts://two.xyz.com` there is another button and when clicked, submits to `htts://two.xyz.com` and responds with a redirect to `https://one.abc.com`.

As everything is happening over https, in both redirections, everything like URL, query params, headers are encrypted.

Using the above setup we can do data exchange between 2 web application using query params.Also, we can do data exchange with auto-form-post (dynamically create form and auto submit using js) instead of query params.

This technique is used in SAML, OIDC for SSO.

Why data exchange using redirection via query params/auto-form-post CANNOT be trusted even on https?

**Please let me know if my following understanding is correct:**

In the described redirect flow from `one.abc.com` to `two.xyz.com` and back to `one.abc.com`, the TLS (Transport Layer Security) encryption is established separately between your browser and each server involved. Let's break down the flow:

**From `one.abc.com` to `two.xyz.com`:**

- When you click on the button on `one.abc.com`, your browser initiates a request to `one.abc.com` over HTTPS (HTTP over TLS).
- `one.abc.com` responds with a redirect response (HTTP 302 Found) instructing your browser to go to `two.xyz.com`.
- Your browser then initiates a new HTTPS request to `two.xyz.com`, establishing a separate TLS connection between your browser and `two.xyz.com`.

**From `two.xyz.com` back to `one.abc.com`:**

- When you click on the button on `two.xyz.com`, your browser initiates a request to `two.xyz.com` over HTTPS (HTTP over TLS).
- `two.xyz.com` responds with a redirect response (HTTP 302 Found) instructing your browser to go to `one.abc.com`.
- Your browser then initiates a new HTTPS request to `one.abc.com`, establishing a separate TLS connection between your browser and `one.abc.com`.

Each of these connections (from your browser to `two.xyz.com` and from your browser back to `one.abc.com`) is encrypted using TLS independently. The TLS encryption ensures the confidentiality and integrity of the communication between your browser and each server, protecting the data exchanged during the redirect flow.

However, there's no direct TLS connection established between `two.xyz.com` and `one.abc.com` during the redirect flow. Instead, the HTTPS connections are terminated and re-established separately at each server endpoint.

For this reason in SAML, IDP signs the SAML assertion and in OIDC, OIDC Provider signs id_token.

Comment: I think this question better fits to Information Security.

Comment: @kelalaka It's not that I don't agree with the proposition, it's just OP may be seeking an answer from our (cryptographic) aspect.